# convert parameterized queries from psycopg2 to pyodbc

Tags: python, psycopg2, pyodbc

I use `psycopg2` code to open an sql file (`postgresql`), and I pass the value for `LIMIT` as a parameter in my code. And it works fine. Here is some of the codes:
.
.

```
cur.execute(open("sample.sql","r").read(),(lim,))
```

.
.

my `sample.sql` creates a table named sample and populates it with some data from another table named `test`

```
CREATE TABLE sample(name varchar(500));
INSERT INTO sample(name) SELECT name FROM test LIMIT %s;
```

`%s` takes the value `lim` passed from `cur.execute`

My question is: how do I translate this into `pyodbc` code to use it in `sql server`?

Comment: Try using `?` instead of `%s` for the parameter placeholder.

Comment: Thanks Gord. ? fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

psycopg2 and pyodbc both implement Python's DB API, and that specification defines several [parameter styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) that can be used. The developers of psycopg2 and pyodbc simply chose different styles:

psycopg2 uses "format" placeholders: `... WHERE city = %s`

pyodbc uses "qmark" placeholders: `... WHERE city = ?`